# Window - click ok button by code

Tags: vb.net, winapi, button

I'm adding a SDE feature class into ArcMap and before it adds in I have to click the **ok** button on the "Connection Details" Window.  Is there a way to click the **ok** button by code?  I was thinking maybe it could be done by using Window notification code (e.g. code below), however I'm not seeing any option for button click **Ok** or Cancel.  Maybe it could be done by "Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ok" somehow or by getting the focus of the **ok** button?

Thanks

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Const WM_CLOSE = &H10 

 'Close SDE connection details dialog
            Dim WinWnd As Long, Ret As String
            'Ask for a Window title
            Ret = "Connection Details"
            If Ret = "" Then Exit Sub
            'Search the window
            WinWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Ret)
            'If WinWnd = 0 Then Messagebox.show "Couldn't find the window ...": Exit Sub
            'Post a message to the window to close itself
            PostMessage WinWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do so:

1. You can find the **OK** button position (using `FindWindowEx` and `GetWindowRect`), place the cursor on the button (`SetCursorPosition`) and simulate a mouse click (`mouse_event`.) Or you can set focus on the button and simulate pressing **Enter** key (with `keyb_event`).
2. Send `BM_CLICK` message to OK button's handle.

I personally like the second approach better:

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Public BM_CLICK As Integer = &HF5 

SendMessage(`OK BUTTON HANDLE`, BM_CLICK, 0, 0); // The button handle can be found with FindWindowEx
```

Comment: What if in Spy++ the window has a handle but the button has no handle or doesn't show up as a child? How do you send a click or press the button in code then?

Comment: Can you please specify what `OK BUTTON HANDLE` is? Are those back ticks supposed to be used like that? It doesn't work for me, though.

Comment: @Xosofox `OK BUTTON HANDLE` (including backticks) must be replaced with the button handle. As I explained already, you can get it with `FindWindow()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be FindWindowEx to find the button on the form?

Comment: Thanks. Problem is, I still can't get my code to find the handle of the button. It is a standard msgbox with a standard "OK" button, but I am not able to click it. I get 0 with this line: Dim hwndButton As Long = FindWindowEx(mainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK") even though mainWindowHandle is set correctly. :-(